# JSON response too large for PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, json

Working with a database I've created, I can run search queries that output data in JSON, then send them back to my webpage.  Pretty standard.

```
$searchQuery  = "SELECT * FROM alldata where $searchBy like '%$searchValue%'" ;
$searchResult = mysqli_query($con, $searchQuery);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($searchResult)) {

$item = array();
    $item["dateReceived"] = convertDate($row[1]);    
    $item["quoteCost"] = $row[15];
    $item["quoteNumber"] = $row[16];
    $item["quoteExpDate"] = convertDate($row[17]);    
    $item["comments"] = $row[21];    

    $output[] = $item; 
    }

$out = array('aaData' => $output);    
echo json_encode($out);
```

When my query is too general, something fails, and I'm not sure where it is.

The response I get from the server is:

```
Fatal error :  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 14680165 bytes) in C:\xampp\htdocs\....php</b> on line <b>74</b><br />
```

My memory limit is set in php.ini as:

```
memory_limit=128M
```

If I go into mySQL and write `SELECT * FROM`alldata`WHERE name like "%a%";` I get about 35,000 rows, each with about 20 columns, but it only takes a split second.

The amount that I can query against the table is prohibitively small - what can I do to fix this so my users can run more generic queries?

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` data directly into a query.

Comment: 128MB seems really low if you're trying to do something like this. Why not crank that up and see if you can get more data? Might also investigate pagination.

Comment: the first thing is to only return data that is required, so get rid of * in your select and actually put in the column names that you are dealing with.

Comment: Have you considered the possibility that you might not actually want to send all of that data to the client at once? If you have 35,000 rows with 20 columns each, that's what, somewhere between 1 and 10 MB of data in the response? Unless this is an export operation—i.e. the user wants to download all the data for further use on another machine—it seems like your users probably don't need all of the data in a single request and would benefit from pagination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way a user is going to want to see all 35,000 rows at once in one page.

This would:

(1) Increase the execution time of the script.

(2) Probably crash the browser trying to display so much of data.

For effective execution of the script use pagination and/or put limits on your queries.

Comment: Yeah, I think all of you are right.  The definite outcry from everyone here means I may want to reconsider this.......

Comment: How are you displaying your data on the front end?

Comment: with DataTables.  I'm going to accept this one - but I appreciate ALL of the responses everyone has left.  I'll resort to LIMIT, and set it at like 500 or something.  that gives them enough control.

Comment: Look up jqGrid. provides a lot of efficient options if that's something similar you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

1. Define output array length upfront => $output=array(mysql_count($query));
2. Include a LIMIT in your sql query

Answer (score 1):

You can try increasing the memory by setting

```
memory_limit=256M
```

or if you're only using it for that query, you can make temporary changes as well

```
<?php
    ini_set('memory_limit', '256M');
```

Of course replace '256M' with the appropriate amount you need.
Be sure to set it back to what it was before, though. You don't want PHP to use up too much memory.

I would also recommend the answer by [96Levels](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4945732/96levels). Use pagination to manage memory more efficiently. However, if you really want to work on all that data at once, you need to increase your memory size.

Comment: If I'm using pagination, the results that are not displayed wouldn't be available to `DataTables'` built-in search though, I don't think.  The goal is to get all 20 of these rows back for as many rows as the user wants to see.  If they want to do a SUPER generic search, and take 5 minutes to load the table, that's their business, not mine.  I wouldn't recommend it, but I also don't want them to get back 0 results.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you should do is increase the `memory_limit` for php either inside your php.ini (search for `memory_limit = 128M` and set it to a higher value. Do not set the value TOO high though or a few requests will result in using all the memory of your server if the scripts are not efficient in the usage. Or you can raise the limit on the fly using `ini_set('memory_limit', '256M');` if the ini_set function is not disabled (Usually hosting providers disable so resources are not abused).

Increasing your memory limit in PHP will only temporarily solve your problem if your database is growing.

The way you are using your query is bad architecture. Queries should never be executed without a LIMIT, especially for large data sets.

There are a couple of things you need to note here, other than raising the already low `memory_limit`. The problem you are currently having (if it is true that the query executed by itself returns a response quickly) is just a matter of allocating enough space for the resulting array/object and its converted string in memory; yet, other problem may cause this now or in the future. I could identify a few here to help you fix this once and for all.

1- Add a limit and a page parameter to your request so you can get the results paginated.

2- Use proper indexing in MySQL for fields you are searching by. It is preferable to have a Full Text index rather than a regular B-Tree index if you are searching in varchar or text fields as it seems you are doing.
[Full-Text Search Functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html)

3- If for some reason you cannot use Full Text search (ex: you have to use InnoDB and not MyISAM) make sure you do not use the wildcard '%' at the beginning of the string as it will not use the index properly (if using regular B-Tree index and not Full Text).

If you absolutely HAVE to use it, I would suggest shifting to Full Text search (if you want to stick to MySQL for search and not use a search engine like [Apache Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/), [Sphinx Search](http://sphinxsearch.com/) or [Elastic Search](https://www.elastic.co/products/elasticsearch) to name a few.

Comment: Yeah, limit was definitely the way to go.  I can set it PRETTY high - I don't think there will be a problem.  Thank you so much!

Comment: You missed the point though. Even though the memory limit was increased and it worked "now", it doesn't mean that it will keep on working.  Consider at least paginating your results so you won't have to process thousands of records at a time.

Comment: I don't think I missed the point.  I added a LIMIT into my sql query, meaning I don't really need to worry about the PHP memory limit.  (Maybe my use of the word `limit` and the fact that it referenced both of those concepts, was confusing).